# How to save camera 2 preview frames?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I would like to save camera2 preview frames in 1 sec. I'm using ImageReader as an output target, and  getting all preview frames in onImageAvailable callback. If I save preview frames directly in this function, I can only get 2 or 3 images in a second. Because image.close() should be called before calling imageReader.acquireLatestImage(). How to save all preview frames in a second.

```
private ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mFrameCallback = imageReader -> {
    Image image = imageReader.acquireLatestImage();
    if (mIsFrameShooting){
        mImageSaver.save(image, createFileName() + ".jpg");
    }else {
        if (image!=null){
            image.close();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I hope that mImageSaver.save() closes the image, too.